How to set a watchpoint for entry in an std::unordered_map?
Minimal Example code:
int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int,int> data = {
        {1,2},
        {2,3},
        {3,4}
    };

    data[4] = 5;
}

I'm breaking on the last line (data[4] =5;). Here, I am attempting to access data[3] but am met with:
(gdb) p data[3] Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.

I'd like to set a watchpoint for one of the entries in an std::unordered_map<int,int>, because a bug in my program is causing one of the entries to dissapear.
My ultimate goal is to detect when a specific key is removed from the unorederd_map. Is this possible?

Set a breakpoint at the standard header file where std::unordered_map is defined.

the symptom you describe sounds like a problem with the maps comparator.

If it's not in memory, it is likely in a register.  Use less optimization to avoid that.  Not sure what compiler you're using, but if you are using a more standard one like gcc or clang, then the option is -O0.  This not only avoids optimization, but also avoids a lot of register allocations for the sake of debuggability.

@Jason even with -O0 its still telling me the address is not in memory

If you dump the whole map in the debugger, do you see everything you'd expect?

@user888379 yes. It will report that the address is not in memory even if I try to access something visible after printing the entire unordered_map

Oh you know what... That's not going to work, because data[4] is not a place in memory.  It's an overloaded function call that GDB cannot understand.  In order to actually access the memory, you would have to know the internal structure layout of unordered_map.  You might be able to do this by "stepping" into (that's s or step in gdb).  Then, you may be able to trace it down to the actual data.  Problem is... every time you add another element, there is chance the map could reallocate and move.

@Jason - That's why I asked about dumping the whole map - gdb knows how to do that.

Yeah, that may be the best option: Dump the data and analyze.  Trying to attach a watchpoint to a value that can move around won't be much fun =]
